# What does the the following memory dump thread from a SharePoint application mean?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, memory-dump

Our SharePoint based web application crashed. Upon inspecting the memory dump, it appeared that 55% of threads calling ISAPI extension OWSSVR were blocked.

Following is one of the thread report from our log. Can someone explain what the report means? To me it appears to be some SQL connection that caused the thread to be hung.

```
Thread 15 - System ID 6000
Entry point   mscorwks!CreateAssemblyCache+71b8 

This thread is calling an ISAPI Extension OWSSVR

Function 
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+a 
mswsock!WSPRecv+66b 
ws2_32!WSARecv+166 
wsock32!recv+38 
dbnetlib!ConnectionRead+4fe 
sqloledb!CDataSource::ConnectionTransact+f7 
sqloledb!CDBConnection::SendPacket+25d 
sqloledb!CStmt::SQLExecRPC+4d4 
sqloledb!CCommand::ExecuteHelper+2a9 
sqloledb!CCommand::Execute+c73 
sqloledb!CImpICommandText::Execute+187 
oledb32!CCommandText::DoExecute+4fc 
oledb32!CCommandText::Execute+8ab 
STSWEL!Voledb::ExecQuery+37e 
STSWEL!VdocumentStore::getSiteProps+ad 
STSWEL!VdbServer::getProps+4d 
OWSSVR!GetExtensionVersion+36657 
mscorwks!IEE+c327 
0x00000642`80747666 
0x00000642`80746aec 
0x00000642`80741c7f 
0x00000642`811e6c3e 
0x00000642`811be397 
0x00000642`811cdd1b 
0x00000642`811bede4 
0x00000642`811e861b 
0x00000642`842a4258 
0x00000642`8035a7c9 
0x00000642`80359ae0 
0x00000642`803269ec 
0x00000642`8035963e 
0x00000642`80358be7 
0x00000642`83a902b3 
0x00000642`83a8ea3c 
System_Web_ni+97651c 
System_Web_ni+2711dd 
System_Web_ni+278b80 
System_Web_ni+2697cb 
System_Web_ni+277ee5 
System_Web_ni+268883 
System_Web_ni+26cba4 
System_Web_ni+26c78c 
System_Web_ni+26b3bc 
mscorwks!IEE+e112 
mscorwks!CompareAssemblyIdentity+72b3 
mscorwks!StrongNameTokenFromPublicKey+b1ee 
mscorwks!CorExeMain2+3986 
mscorwks!CreateApplicationContext+167d0 
mscorwks!CompareAssemblyIdentity+15da2 
mscorwks!IEE+e28e 
webengine!DisposeAppDomainsIndirect+9b3 
webengine!IsManagedDebuggerConnectedIndirect+73 
webengine!SetMinRequestsExecutingToDetectDeadlock+284 
mscorwks!CompareAssemblyIdentity+89027 
mscorwks!CompareAssemblyIdentity+774ba 
mscorwks!CreateAssemblyCache+71b8 
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+3a
```

Comment: It is a dll designed for SQL clients by Microsoft. Here is a link that explains your question. http://dll.paretologic.com/detail.php/dbnetlib

Comment: I'd first to check if there's deadlocks in SQL server